# nested xml to be parsed at samelevel using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT transformation and have a below requirement:

I have a xml in following form

```
<ServiceOrder>
<Order>
<OrderNumber>1</OrderNumber>
 <OrderType>abc</OrderType>
      <Order>
      <OrderNumber>10</OrderNumber>
      <OrderType>xyz</OrderType>`enter code here`
      </Order>
</Order>
</ServiceOrder>
```

Expected Output:

```
<ServiceOrder>
<Order>
 <OrderNumber>1</OrderNumber>
 <OrderType>abc</OrderType>
 </Order>
 <Order>
 <OrderNumber>10</OrderNumber>
 <OrderType>xyz</OrderType>
 </Order>
</ServiceOrder>
```

I need help on how to transform all the nested orders in the same level.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried something so far? Please post your try here.

Comment: Thanks Lingamurthy for your reply, This is the XSLT i tried:

Comment: <xsl:template match="ServiceOrder">
<Product>
<xsl:apply-templates select="Order" />
</Product>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Order">
<orderLineNo>
<xsl:value-of select="./OrderNumber"/>
</orderLineNo>
<OrderType>
<xsl:value-of select="./OrderType"/>
</OrderType>
<xsl:if test="Order">
<Product>
<xsl:apply-templates select="Order" />
</Product>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: I am getting output as;

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Product>
   <orderLineNo>1</orderLineNo>
   <OrderType>abc</OrderType>
   <Product>
      <orderLineNo>10</orderLineNo>
      <OrderType>xyz</OrderType>
   </Product>
</Product>

Comment: Can you add the XSLT to your question, as it is hard to read code in comments. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `Order` elements are nested, the instead of select the `Order` elements that are direct children of `ServiceOrder`, select all descendant ones instead:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select=".//Order" />
```

Then you just have a template matching `Order` as before, but it does not need to contain any template that selects other `Order` elements within it.

Try this XSTL

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="ServiceOrder">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".//Order" /> 
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="Order"> 
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="OrderNumber" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="OrderType" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Alternatively, instead of explicitly selecting `Order` elements, you can use an `<xsl:apply-templates select="Order" />` within the `Order` template, but place it after the creation of the element.

Try this XSLT too

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="Order"> 
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="OrderNumber" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="OrderType" />
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Order" /> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```